# Redirect on POST

Tags: javascript, html, post

I am building a web app using javascript (client and server) in which I want to send information to the server, but I don't want to send it in the URL, so I want to use a POST message.
The thing is the server should redirect me based on that information I am sending, but as I am not using GET the new page will not load.
Any suggestions?

Comment: "as I am not using GET the new page will not load" - that shouldn't matter, or I totally don't understand the problem.  Your server side script should be able to redirect the client wherever you need.

Comment: I think he wants to get the URL he is redirecting to from the header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're using an ajax method to send the data? if so on the success function just add a:

```
document.location='http://www.google.com'
```

if you post some code it'll be easier to help though